# Can’t bind to ‘lazyLoad’ since it isn’t a known property of ‘img’ - Ionic 4 - ng-lazy-load

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading, ionic4

I am trying to get lazyLoad to work on my Ionic 4 app. I have imported it on my app.module.ts, and are trying to use it on my page. I’m not sure what the issue is and any help is greatly appreciated.

app.module.ts

```
import { LazyLoadImageModule, intersectionObserverPreset } from 'ng-lazyload-image'; 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule, IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),LazyLoadImageModule.forRoot({preset: intersectionObserverPreset})],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Insomnia,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

my page.html

```
<ion-col size="2" *ngFor="let movie of browseResults| keyvalue">
        <div class="rating">&#9734; {{movie.value.rating}}</div>
        <img (click)="movieDetails(movie.value.stream_id)" (keyup.enter)="movieDetails(movie.value.stream_id)"  [lazyLoad]="movie.value.stream_icon" class="browse-image focusable">
      </ion-col>
```

And I'm importing it on the component.ts for this page but not sure what else to do. It's not really being used on the component.

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's because lazy loading is a new-ish _browser_ feature, and it's not yet available in the ionic framework yet.

Comment: hmm, ionic framework is using angular 8. so i would think it would be. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Can you please post code for other module where that component is used

Comment: Im not really doing anything with it on the component. It should just work right ? i think this is where im confused.

Comment: Try `[attr.lazyLoad]`

Comment: Trying getting rid of .forRoot({ preset: intersectionObserverPreset }) and update ng lazyload to 8.0.1